# Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Today I run .exe file from Visual Studio's debug folder and it appears an Invalid Null Pointer error from this section of code

- Error : Debug Assertion Failed

  - Program : C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP110D.dll
  - File : E:\visual studio 11\vc\include\xstring
  - Line : 1143
  - Expression : Invalid Null Pointer

I mostly done the code, but there are one problem with a line of code. It keeps saying the error because of the 4th line ( the one that I bold ) :

```
void main(int argc,const char *argv[])
{
string a, HauTo;
**string fileName(argv[1]);**
StackC s;
InitS(s); //Initialize an empty stack 

fstream fi, fo;
fi.open(fileName, ios::in);
fo.open("Output.txt", ios::out);
getline(fi, a);
```

I'm doing an assignment so it would be grateful if someone help me with this.

Comment: You probably haven't passed any command line arguments to the program. Check `argc > 1` before trying to use `argv[1]`.

Comment: If you run the program by double-clicking the .exe, you haven't passed any arguments to the program.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how you run this, but note that you have an `argc` which you didn't check.

This says how many args you sent in to main.

If you try to access `argv[1]` and there is only one arg (`argv[0]` - the program name itself) you have an error.

---

If you specifically wish to pass parameters or "Command arguments" inside Visual Studio, right click on the project and go to "Properties". Then find "Debugging" and enter you arguments there

[image]